# Why `init` cannot be used in `NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] init]`?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Why `init` cannot be used in `NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] init]` since `init` is an instance method that every class has?

Comment: Apple has tagged it this way because `NSCalendar` has a designated initializer that takes a calendar identifier.  They don't want you using `init` because it won't be properly initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSCalendar has to be initiated like this:

`NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];`

Without specifying what kind of calendar your want, the instance would be useless. This is how the framework prevents you from initializing useless objects.

Comment: This helped, thanks..I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 it says:
'NSGregorianCalendar' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.10 - Use NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian instead